# Issue in truffle unbox zeppelinos/zepkit

Tags: truffle-box, openzeppelin-sdk

[image]

As it is visible in the screenshot, I did not get a green check in the "setting up box". Anyone know why it is happening and will it cause any issue in the future?

Comment: try unboxing as admin

Comment: tried but getting the same issue.

Comment: it works by me (on windows) it took some time, try 'npm install' manually  after unboxing

Comment: yes, I run 'npm install' manually after unboxing and everything working fine. but I am just curious to know the reason behind that red cross in front of 'setting up box'.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to `truffle unbox zeppelinos/zepkit` though on Windows Subsystem for Linux on my laptop it took a while (4-5 minutes).

I see that you raised this as an issue in GitHub where the advice was to use `zos unpack tutorial` that you did successfully using the current version of zos.
https://github.com/zeppelinos/zepkit/issues/30

If you have more questions about ZepKit you can always ask in the [community forum](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/)

Comment: thanks, @abcoathup, Now I will ask everything related to Zeppelin on the community forum. I think the problem was with my nodejs and npm which is resolved now. I guess I should remove this post from here.

Comment: Questions in stackexchange are fine too